# Recovering access to localhost web login after forgetting password and reinstallation

Tags: server, service, webbrowser-control, local, host

I had a web login at 127.0.0.1:8080 to run a service as the server.
After the PC went down, I used another PC to run service. Now the previous PC was fixed and I'm trying to run it as the server again.
Unfortunately I've forgotten the password to the login and also the reinstallation of the service has not given me the default admin login.
Can someone help?

I tried doing proxy reset and malware scan but it hasn't changed.